# How to get the array index of an XML element in MSXML - VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have a requirement to convert the XML files to Excel. So I want to retrieve the XML as name value pairs and uniquely name the columns. Is there any method to get the XML array index of a node? Below is the sample XML where I want to know the index of *productInfo* fields.

```
<productInfoRequest>
    <CheckIn>false</CheckIn>
    <timeStamp>2016-11-02T15:49:57.337-05:00</timeStamp>
    <foodoInfo>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
    </foodoInfo>
    <productInfo>
        <itemNo>1</itemNo>
        <itemName>Sample</itemName>
    </productInfo>
    <productInfo>
        <itemNo>2</itemNo>
        <itemName>Sample</itemName>
    </productInfo>
    <productInfo>
        <itemNo>3</itemNo>
        <itemName>Sample</itemName>
    </productInfo>
    <productInfo>
        <itemNo>4</itemNo>
        <itemName>Sample</itemName>
    </productInfo>
</productInfoRequest>
```

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Raivn.png)

Please note that this is just a sample request xml which i have given. Any given XML should be converted into unique key value pair keys and loaded into excel

Sample code snippet :

```vb
Sub GenKeyValues()

    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim cNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim ccNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim KeyNo As Variant
    Dim dic

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim CurrVal
    Dim Cnt As Integer

    CurrVal = <<<<<Im reading the XML from the file to a string from another method>>>>>
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    With xmlDoc
        .async = False
        .validateOnParse = True
        .LoadXML CurrVal
    End With

    Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.ChildNodes

    cnt = 0

    For Each xNode In xmlNodes

        If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
             For Each cNode In xNode.ChildNodes
                 If cNode.ChildNodes.Length > 1 Then
                     cnt = cnt + 1
                          For Each ccNode In cNode.ChildNodes
                              Key = ccNode.ParentNode.BaseName + CStr(cnt) + "_" + ccNode.BaseName
                              Val = ccNode.nodeTypedValue
                              dic.Add Key, Val
                          Next
                 Else
                    Key = cNode.BaseName
                    Val = cNode.nodeTypedValue
                    dic.Add Key, Val
                 End If
             Next
       End If
    Next

    For Each KeyNo In dic.Keys
       MsgBox ("Key: " & KeyNo & " Value: " & dic(KeyNo))
    Next

End Sub
```

I have retrieve the keys as below :

```
foodoInfo0_Country
foodoInfo0_Currency
productInfo0_itemNo
productInfo0_itemName
productInfo1_itemNo
productInfo1_itemName
productInfo2_itemNo
```

productInfo2_itemName

Comment: *I want to retrieve the XML as name value pairs and uniquely name the columns*...please show us with data what this looks like and even what is wrong with current code. Errors? Undesired output?

Comment: Hi Parfait, Nothing wrong with the current current and its working. But in generating key value pairs i have to retrieve the element - values  uniquely.  In my case, productInfo is an XML array and has child node(eg ItemNo). Right now im able to get the parent node but not the index of the parent node in the array of elements. When im retrieving the child nodes of product Info, i need to know the index of ProductInfo for which i m retrieving. The Keys should look like ProductInfo0_ItemNo, ProductInfo1_ItemNo. This will make my Key Value pairs unique.

Comment: Key = ccNode.ParentNode.BaseName + CStr(cnt) + "_" + ccNode.BaseName. Here im getting the parent node only ProductInfo but i need to get it like like ProductInfo[0], ProductInfo[1]......

Comment: Please edit your post with this information showing the Excel tabular output.

Comment: Hi Parfait - I um unable to paste the table but i have added the comment how  i need to get the keys

Comment: Not sure I still understand. Can you just post your desired output? What is *foodoInfo0*? Is this the literal or to be replaced with XML data?

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to tranform XML files into end-use formats including other XML files, HTML files, even text files. Here, XSLT can transform your structure into a CSV format with needed headers and data rows. MSXML can run XSLT 1.0 scripts, avoiding nested `for` and `if` logic and use of arrays or dictionaries.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file to be read in VBA; note: XSL scripts are XML files)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/> 
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/productInfoRequest">      
      <xsl:call-template name="rows">
        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="foodoInfo|productInfo"/>
      </xsl:call-template>   
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="rows">
      <xsl:param name="data"/>

      <!-- HEADERS -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$data">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), position(), '_', name(*[1]))"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), position(), '_', name(*[2]))"/>        
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

      <!-- DATA -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$data">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(node()[1], ',', node()[2])"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**VBA**

```vb
Public Sub RunXSLTtoCSV()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim txtOutput As String, csvfile As String

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL
    xmlDoc.LoadXML CurrVal
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLScript.xsl"
    xslDoc.async = False

    ' TRANSFORM TO TEXT
    txtOutput = xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc)

    ' SAVE TO CSV
    csvfile = "C:\Path\To\CSV.csv"
    Open csvfile For Output As #1
        Print #1, txtOutput
    Close #1

    Set xslDoc = Nothing
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

**CSV** Output

*Of course this is a csv file and not Excel workbook. Hence, save or load content into a workbook.*

[image: CSV Output Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a magic pill wish will automatically convert everything for you or perhaps I simply don't understand your end result. However, XML is a standard and when you are receiving XML you usually agree on what and how you're going to receive it. That being said, I don't quite understand what the problem is that you are having with reading the root element like I do. `("/productInfoRequest")` If this element is not the root element than what is? 
In order to parse the way, you want to parse we would have to make a few changes to the way we read the XML. Look at the updated code and run it. This will print the values and add the values to the dictionary the way that you described in your las comment.
Again, you will need to add a reference to the Microsoft XML, V6.0 library by going to  **Tools -> References.**

Here is the code.

```
Sub GenKeyValues()

    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim cNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim ccNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim KeyNo As Variant
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim oXml As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim tempProduct As Variant
    Dim ItemName As String
    Dim ItemValue As String

    Set oXml = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

     XML = "<productInfoRequest>  <CheckIn>false</CheckIn> <timeStamp>2016-11-02T15:49:57.337-05:00</timeStamp>  <foodoInfo>  <Country>USA</Country>" + _
       "<Currency>USD</Currency>   </foodoInfo>   <productInfo>   <itemNo>1</itemNo>   <itemName>Sample</itemName>   </productInfo>   <productInfo>   <itemNo>2</itemNo>" + _
  "<itemName>Sample</itemName>   </productInfo>   <productInfo>   <itemNo>3</itemNo>   <itemName>Sample</itemName>   </productInfo>   <productInfo>   <itemNo>4</itemNo>" + _
  "<itemName>Sample</itemName>   </productInfo>   </productInfoRequest> "

     oXml.LoadXML XML

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set productdic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim CurrVal
    Dim Cnt As Integer

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

    With xmlDoc
        .async = False
        .validateOnParse = True
        .LoadXML CurrVal
    End With

    Set xmlNodes = oXml.SelectNodes("/productInfoRequest")
    Set productNodes = oXml.SelectNodes("/productInfoRequest/productInfo")

    Cnt = 0
    pcnt = 0

   For Each xNode In productNodes

        If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
             For Each cNode In xNode.ChildNodes
          ' by product loop the children and add once completed 
          ' add it to the dictionary
                  If cNode.BaseName = "itemName" Then
                     ItemName = cNode.BaseName
                     tempProduct = Array("product_Info" & CStr(pcnt) & cNode.BaseName)
                     tempProduct = Array(cNode.nodeTypedValue)
                     End If

                     If cNode.BaseName = "itemNo" Then
                     ItemValue = cNode.nodeTypedValue

                     End If

             Next

             Key = "productInfo" & CStr(pcnt) & "_" & ItemName
             val = ItemValue
             productdic.Add Key, val
             pcnt = pcnt + 1

       End If
    Next



    For Each xNode In xmlNodes

        If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
             For Each cNode In xNode.ChildNodes
                 If cNode.ChildNodes.Length > 1 Then
                     Cnt = Cnt + 1
                          For Each ccNode In cNode.ChildNodes
                              Key = ccNode.ParentNode.BaseName + CStr(Cnt) + "_" + ccNode.BaseName
                              val = ccNode.nodeTypedValue
                              dic.Add Key, val
                          Next
                 Else
                    Key = cNode.BaseName
                    val = cNode.nodeTypedValue
                    dic.Add Key, val
                 End If
             Next
       End If
    Next

'    For Each KeyNo In dic.Keys
'    Debug.Print ("Key: " & KeyNo & " Value: " & dic(KeyNo))
'    Next

     For Each KeyNo In productdic.Keys
     Debug.Print ("Key: " & KeyNo & " Value: " & productdic(KeyNo))

    Next


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Miguel, Thank you for your response. i have already implemented a solution. But only challenge i m having is that, im unable have unique key value pairs. I need to get the index of the parent(product Info) when i m parsing the child values so that i can have unique references in the excel when creating. Im planning to use dictionary and load the values. The key should be like productinfo1_itemNo, productinfo2_itemNO. Here i have to get the array position of the product info and append it to the key to make it as unique

Comment: Ok, can you update the post with your solution and I'll help you get to what you want.

Comment: Hi Miguel - I have attached a sample code snippet which is only relevant to our topic. Here i have used cnt and appended to make it as unique somehow but i wanted to know the index of the xml element array so that it can write into an dictionary and excel without duplicate keys. Pl. note i may not able to use XPATH as i have deal with different formats of XML using the same code..

Comment: @Vinoth the code you provided above had several issues, which I fixed. The key in the dictionary is the value from the XML tag name if you want to change the key to a number value pair that's easily done by replacing the key with `cnt` instead

Comment: Key = ccNode.ParentNode.BaseName + CStr(cnt) + "_" + ccNode.BaseName. Here im getting the parent node name as only ProductInfo.but i need to get it like like ProductInfo[0], ProductInfo[1] so that when i m loading as Key i shall change it as ProductInfo0_ItemNo, ProductInfo1_ItemNo. etc.,

Comment: I don't understand your explanation at all, the XML element product info has several product info elements. The code I provided you already contains the product info with a number sequence, do you want to have a separate array with just product info  so you can access the product info by index? is that what you want to do?

Comment: Hi Miguel - Sorry, let me try to explain clearly on the whole. I cannot load the XML using the XPATH as you did because i need to read XML's of different payloads from the file and i might not be knowing before what is coming. So i cannot use "Set xmlNodes = oXml.SelectNodes("/productInfoRequest")"
I have to read the XML's from a file and generate key value pairs and load it into excel row for each XML. While loading the excel the column names should be XML Element names.

Comment: example :  I should convert "<productInfo>   <itemNo>1</itemNo>   <itemName>Sample</itemName> "                                                                  Keys = productinfo0_itemNo, productInfo0_itemName where 0 represents first element in the XML array                                                                       Value = 1 , Sample.

Comment: Hi Miguel, Will you pl. point me what is the change we have to do inorder to get the index of productinfo. I dont see any change in the code. But the output in the screen image is what i expected. foodoInfo0_Country
foodoInfo0_Currency
productInfo0_itemNo
productInfo0_itemName
productInfo1_itemNo
productInfo1_itemName
productInfo2_itemNo
productInfo2_itemName

Comment: Hi Miguel , Thank you. Im looking for a generalized solution and cannot use XPATH and select nodes. oXml.SelectNodes("/productInfoRequest/productInfo") Is there any generalized way to get the array of the parent element like : foodoInfo0_Country foodoInfo0_Currency productInfo0_itemNo productInfo0_itemName productInfo1_itemNo